# How can I print the location information I get in the background from logcat to a text file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

In my project, I print the location information I get in the background every 4 seconds to logcat. But I want to print from logcat to text file or to text in android studio. How do I do this?

The code block I printed to logcat:

```
if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
                double latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                double longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
                Log.d("LOCATION_UPDATE", latitude + ", " + longitude);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called a GPX file.

Check out this library for handling GPX files
https://github.com/jenetics/jpx